# BitmapButtonField Listener

Tags: button, bitmap

In application I have implemented BitmapButtonField with image. On click of BitmapButton I have to integrate Facebook application. I searched for click event of bitmapButtonField but nothing is working.

```
Facebook = new BitmapButtonField(
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource("facebook.png"));
    Facebook.setMargin(0, 10, 0, 10);
    horizontal_field.add(Facebook);
    Facebook.setChangeListener(this);
```

If I'm testing this on touch listener phone. Its is working. If we have device without touch its not working.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a **BlackBerry** question?  You didn't tag the question with the `blackberry` tag, so it probably won't get noticed.  Also, if it is BlackBerry, is your `BitmapButtonField` class [this one from the Advanced UI library](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BitmapButtonField.java)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the style property **ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK**. So you can make the button clickable. you can use this constructor of the BitmapButtonField Class

```
BitmapButtonField( Bitmap normalState, Bitmap focusState, long style )
```

for exaple:

```
Facebook = new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("facebook.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("facebookFocusState.png"), ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```

That worked for me. on trackPad BlackBerry Phones